# Java - floating point calc in functional style

Tags: java, functional-programming, floating-point, double, precision

I guess here `sm` and `sm2` are not equal due to floating point limitaitons:

```
double sm = -1.22 + (0.6027852837247973 + 0.8920332205475238);
double sm2 = -1.22 + 0.6027852837247973 + 0.8920332205475238;
System.out.println("sm = "+sm);
System.out.println("sm2 = "+sm2);
System.out.println("sm-sm2 = "+(sm-sm2));
```

and the result is:

```
sm = 0.27481850427232124
sm2 = 0.27481850427232113
sm-sm2 = 1.1102230246251565E-16
```

I guess it is not zero because of order of operations?

Anyway, what I wanted to ask in this case is - how to have equivalent of this code:

```
double r2 = 0;
for(double o : ar){
  r2+=o*2;
}
r2 -= k;
```

in functional style (e.g. like this, but since it is first operation I have problematic output):

```
Arrays.stream(ar)
    .map(o -> o*2)
    .reduce(-k, Double::sum);
```

Comment: Why not just do map to multiply -> sum starting from zero -> subtract from the result? So, same order of operations as the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, **the order of operations matters**. When you use streams, there is no guarantee on the order of execution. Besides this, there is another issue in your approach with streams, and that's the value of the `identity` parameter - `k` in your case (I assume you want to subtract some non-zero value from the result). The value of the identity and the accumulator function in the `reduce(double identity, DoubleBinaryOperator accumulator)` must be such that the following statement is always true:

```
accumulator.apply(identity, x) = x // for any value of x
```

Having the accumulator `Double::sum` (same as `(d1, d2) -> Double.sum(d1, d2)`) the only value for a valid identity is 0.

JavaDoc reference:

> > **double java.util.stream.DoubleStream.reduce(double identity, DoubleBinaryOperator op)**
> >
> > Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using the provided identity value and an associative accumulation function, and returns the reduced value. This is equivalent to:
> >
> > ```
> > double result = identity;
> >      for (double element : this stream)
> >          result = accumulator.applyAsDouble(result, element)
> >      return result;
> > ```
> >
> > but is not constrained to execute sequentially.
> >     The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for all x, accumulator.apply(identity, x) is equal to x. The accumulator function must be an associative function.
> >
> > This is a terminal operation.

You could try something like this (as @VLAZ suggested):

```
double calculate(double[] values, double k) {
    return DoubleStream.of(values).map(d -> d * 2).reduce(0, Double::sum) - k;
}
```

---

### UPDATE

As suggested by @LouisWasserman, the `calculate` method can be simplified by replacing `reduce(0, Double::sum)` with `sum()`:

```
double calculate(double[] values, double k) {
    return DoubleStream.of(values).map(d -> d * 2).sum() - k;
}
```

Comment: `DoubleStream.reduce(0, Double::sum)` can probably be done strictly better as `DoubleStream.sum()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, that's correct. I used `DoubleStream.reduce(0, Double::sum)` to emphasise the importance of the identity. Otherwise, `DoubleStream.sum()` is more appropriate in this case, I agree.

Comment: @ahoxha OK, I guess I was overcomplicating it... just it didn't look nice to have that `-k` in the end (no idea why ::) I also use `Arrays.stream(values).map(d -> d * 2).sum() - k;` since then I can use one class for all primitive types.